# Why do the objects created in a loop have the same address?

Tags: c++, pointers

I do see some other questions that look like mine, but I still can't figure this out.

Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename Data_Type>
    class node {
        public:
        Data_Type data;
        node* next;
        node(Data_Type data, node* next){
            this->data = data;
            this->next = next;
        }
    };


int main(){
    vector<node<int> > vectorOfNodes;
    for (int i = 0; i< 4; i++){ 
        node<int> newNode = node<int>(i,NULL);
        std::cout << "new node address a "<<    &newNode << "\n";
        vectorOfNodes.push_back(newNode);
        std::cout << "new node address b "<<    &vectorOfNodes[i] << "\n";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i< 4; i++){ 
        std::cout << "data "<<    vectorOfNodes[i].data << "\n";
    }
}
```

When I run this, "new node address a " is always the same address repeated each iteration but "new node address b " is a different address each time.

```
new node address a 0x7fff546c39b0
new node address b 0x7fe2f8c039d0
new node address a 0x7fff546c39b0
new node address b 0x7fe2f8c039f0
new node address a 0x7fff546c39b0
new node address b 0x7fe2f8c03a20
new node address a 0x7fff546c39b0
new node address b 0x7fe2f8c03a30
data 0
data 1
data 2
data 3
```

I don't understand why a and b aren't the same.  More specifically: isn't &newNode the address of the object I just created? And isn't vectorOfNodes[i] also that object? So isn't &vectorOfNodes[i] also the address of the object?

Comment: a and b aren't the same because they're different objects at different memory locations. a is probably the same each iteration because that memory address can be reused for each iteration as an optimization measure.

Comment: Isn't &newNode the address of the object I just created?  And isn't vectorOfNodes[i] also that object?  So isn't &vectorOfNodes[i] also the address of the object?

Comment: You can replace `node<int> newNode = node<int>(i, NULL);` with `node<int> newNode(i, NULL);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This stuff is explained in every college-level course on operating system design and/or compiler design.

The objects in question are instantiated on the stack, and at the end of the scope, they go out of scope on the stack. The stack grows and shrinks accordingly, and because on every iteration of the loop, the same exact objects get created (and destroyed), the stack grows and shrinks by the same amount, so the same objects always end up getting instantiated at the same location on the stack.

In practice, the compiler can do some optimizations and figure out the large amount of stack each function will use, most of the time, and thus "pregrow" the stack to the large amount the function will need; but that's going a bit too far into the weeds...

This is as concise answer as I can give, without going into an entire lecture of what a stack is, etc...

Now, the other object is allocated on the heap. Focus your attention on the fact that, at the end of the loop, the object you stuffed into the vector *still* exists, while the "a" object gets destroyed, and you'll begin to see the difference. On each iteration of the loop the "a" object gets created, and then destroyed at the end of the loop (and get created at the beginning of the loop again), while the object you stuffed into the vector still exists.

Comment: That was very clear and helpful.  Is it necessary to first put the object on the stack and then copy it to the heap?  Could I have skipped the first step somehow?

Comment: Sure. You could've simply written: vectorOfNodes.push_back(node<int>(i,NULL)); In fact, if you get rid of the dumps to std::cout, and compile your code with a high-enough optimization level, the compiler will likely optimize the code this way automatically (depending on what the compiler can figure out about your class's copy constructors).

Answer (score 0):

The push_back operation copies newNode into the vector. Therefore each copy is at a different address.

Answer (score -2):

Here;

```
node<int> newNode = node<int>(i,NULL);
```

You are not creating a new node, just assigning a new value to it.

New nodes are being created inside the vector using the default copy constructor. If you want your vector to contain the nodes you are pushing into it you should use a pointer, like this;

```
vector<node<int>*> vectorOfNodes;
```

Comment: This is a declaration statement. It creates a new object of type `node<int>`, and initializes it.

Comment: @EJP That initialization is a copy construction.

Comment: @douyw It's "copy initialization", the compiler is permitted to do copy elision, but the copy constructor must be accessible.